# How to fix relative paths when router used (ExpressJS)

Tags: node.js, express, path, pug

The paths in my layout jade file which is getting extended are looking like this:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='../lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='../lib/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')
```

So it's all OK if my Link is something like
`www.url.com/admin/` 
but when I call
`www.url.com/admin/blog/new` 
the pathing of course is wrong. It would need to look like `href='../../lib/...'` because the routing looks like this:

```
router.get('/admin/blog/new', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('admin/blog-new', {title: 'Post Blog Entry'});
})
```

So is there a possibility to fix this easy besides absolute pathing? (maybe I'm a blockhead right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out, that by using a leading `/` you can reference to the base path which solved the problem for me by changing the path to

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/../lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/../lib/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can serve your lib folder as named static, and after that you can get rid of the relative paths.

```
app.use('/vendor',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/vendor')));
```

So as you can see in my root directory i have a **client** folder where i store all the downloaded libs inside the **vendor** folder. So i mapped the static path as **/vendor**.

Now in view we can refer to libs as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
```